# Spring Integration move file to another folder then send to sftp server

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I would like create an app where in i will listen to a 
folder named "input" for a text file then move the text file to "output"
then send it to sftp server.
here is my code in Spring Integration.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow textFileIntegration(@Value("${input.dir}") File in,
                                   @Value("${output.dir}") File out,
                                   MessageChannel sftpChannel) {

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Files.inboundAdapter(in)
                            .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                            .patternFilter("*.txt"),
                    sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec ->
                            sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec.poller(pollerFactory -> pollerFactory.fixedRate(1000)))
            //.transform(File.class, file -> service.process(file)) commented on purpose
            .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(out))
            .channel(sftpChannel)
            .get();
}
```

Now what's happening is when i put the text file in "input" directory, the file then successfully move to "output" directory but the sending to sftp channel don't work. I tried commenting the handle method and sftp channel will work.
I just want to put first the file to output directory before sending it to sftp.
I see a "route" function in Spring Integration DSL but not sure if that's the right one to use.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For such a flow you should use a `Files.outboundGateway()` instead of one-way `Files.outboundAdapter()`. The problem with the last one that it just doesn't produce a reply to be sent to the next channel.

Another problem that `FileWritingMessageHandler` is able to produce a reply when it is in the *gateway* mode, so it allows to configure a `setOutputChannel()`.

I think we may consider to reject such a configuration if it is not about `Files.outboundGateway()`.

Please, see more info in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#file-writing-output-gateway

Answer (score -3):

File HANDLER in Spring :D

Not sure about my answer

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" directory="/inbound">
 <int:poller fixed-delay="1000"/>
  </file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut" directory="/outbound"/>

  <int:service-activator input-channel="filesIn"
                   output-channel="filesOut"
                   ref="handler"/>
```